# How to access particular root in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about firebase.

I have a firebase database and wanted to ask how can I access the date root? What should I write while initializing the `databaseReference`. In this case 12 Apr 08:48 AM

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) here.

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street");

List<Street> streetList = new ArrayList<Street>();    

ValueEventListener streetListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot streetSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String date = streetSnapshot.getKey(); // This will give you 12 Apr 08:48 AM for the first entry
            Street street = streetSnapshot.getValue(Street.class);
            streetList.add(street);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Street failed, log a message
    }
};

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(streetListener);
```

And the `Street.java` class should look like.

```
public class Street {
    public String DateTime; 
    public String Likes;
    public String Long_Desc;
    public String Short_Desc;
    public String UserName;
    public String VideoName;
    public String VideoPath;  

    // ... Other variables    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference userlistReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
Query donors = userlistReference.orderByChild("Email");
    donors.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildren() != null)
            {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String uid = snapshot.getKey();     
                if (snapshot.getValue() != null)
                    {
                        if (snapshot.child("Name").getValue() != null)
                        {
                            name = snapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            name = "";
                        }
                        if (snapshot.child("Email").getValue()  != null)
                        {
                            email = snapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            email = "";
                        }
                    }
}
```

You can do something like this according to your problem. You have to move on your child whose root is required then you'll have to call getKey() function to get the root. I've shared the code of my own project and it is working for me. It is the same situation as yours. I had to get uid in my case and I got it through snapshot.getKey(). You can check my image through this link.
[This is in my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47MiW.png)

Now according to my case you should try

```
DatabaseReference userlistReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street");
Query donors = userlistReference.orderByChild("DateTime");
    donors.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildren() != null)
            {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String date = snapshot.getKey();     
                }
            }
        }
}
```